# how to delete my self connection in firebird before close application?

Tags: delphi, transactions, firebird2.1

I want view all conncetions inside in the table "MON$ATTACHMENTS", but can´t delete a especific record. When delete return error : "Operation not supported".

```
  DELETE FROM mon$attachments
   WHERE mon$attachment_id IN (
                               SELECT mon$attachment_id
                                 FROM mon$attachments
                                WHERE  mon$attachment_id = current_connection
                              )
```

Result is : "Operation not supported"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported in Firebird 2.1, terminating connections by deleting from `MON$ATTACHMENTS` was [added in Firebird 2.5](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/rlsnotes252.html#rnfb25-mon-trmntclnt) (<sub>The title says 2.1, but these are the 2.5 releasenotes</sub>). It requires that the database is ODS 11.2 (the database format version of Firebird 2.5).

The query you use is convoluted (why not just `DELETE FROM mon$attachments WHERE mon$attachment_id = current_connection`), but it also makes no sense: If you want to kill your current connection, then just close the connection (note: I don't know Delphi, but I assume there is way to close a connection)! It is easier, faster and better.